# Can exe files have a port?

Tags: windows, port

In order to assign a port to Jmeter, I want a port number for the exe file. I found it by `netstat -a -b` but the thing is, the exe is running on dynamic ports. So each time it runs port changes. I want to know how to set a specific port for the exe. since it's not ASP.NET Development Server, I can't use this answer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Is it possible to assign  a port to  exe  when it is not a server?

Comment: With the little information you have provided about the application in question the answer is no.

Comment: @Seth Can you please explain more or share a link? I want to know which type of exe can have a port number? like condition to satisfy to have a port

Comment: An exe file can't have a port number. If you're just looking at an exe file you will likely not be able to determine whenever it's going to try to use the network at all. It's up to the actual programming and execution of the applications logic. Look into the additional information for your application. Maybe consider using different filters like destination addresses or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a port to an executable in the sense that you force an executable to use a specific port.

The developer basically programs what port it will be using. In case of a server application, the developer often adds a function to specify the port from the settings, but when it comes to connecting to a server (a client) a dynamic port is often used.

First a static port is used to initiate the connection, then its switched to a dynamic port, to free up the listening port.

There is no other way. You can see if you can allow jmeter to query the port itself by using the path of the exefile, but that's about  all you can do.